# How to build gattlib

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I am trying to build the gattlib for Raspbian for Raspberry Pi 3. But when followed the instructions on the site: https://github.com/labapart/gattlib and using Linaro cross-compiling toolchain, I was not able to do this in Ubuntu 16.04. Please advise me, if possible, in details what is the correct way to do this. Thanks.

Comment: I was able to CMAKE but when applying MAKE, got error: #include_next <limits.h>  /* recurse down to the real one */. Please advis eme how to compile correctly.

Comment: Did you check the opened issues at the github's page? This could be related to your problem https://github.com/labapart/gattlib/issues/66

Comment: Here is the most important part of this error report:

$make
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib.h:30,
                 from ../Downloads/GATTLIB/gattlib-master/dbus/gattlib.c:24:
../Toolchains/gcc-linaro-4.9-2015.05-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9.3/include-fixed/limits.h:168:61: fatal error: limits.h: No such file or directory
 #include_next <limits.h>  /* recurse down to the real one */
                                                             ^
compilation terminated.
...

Comment: Thank you James. Yes, the changes you mentioned were necessary. But still I am getting the same error. Please advise me how to fix this problem. Thanks.

Comment: I was able to successfully built the GATTLIB in my Raspberry Pi 3 board but still wonder what should be the problem with building it in my PC Ubuntu environment. Please advise me.